# ¿Cómo encuentro el menor y mayor valor de entre una lista de enteros?

Tags: javascript

No encuentro el error en este codigo;
El objetivo es encontrar el numero mas alto y el mas bajo segun una string entregada.

```
function highAndLow(numbers){
    var alto = numbers[0];
    var bajo = numbers[0];
    var arr = numbers.split(' ');

    for (i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
    var num = arr[i];

     if(num>=alto){
      alto = num;
      } else
      if(num<=bajo){
        bajo = num;
      }
     }

    return alto + ' ' + bajo;
}
```

Al ejecutarlo con la siguiente string:

```
highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6");
```

El resultado me da "6 -214", que es incorrecto porque el máximo es 542 y no 6.

No encuentro qué hice mal.

Answer (score 10):

El problema es que comparas cadenas de texto, por lo que "6" es mayor que "542". Te falta hacer la conversion a numero mediante `parseFloat()`.

Aquí tu código con los cambios:

```js
//funcion que obtiene el numero Maximo y Minimo dentro de un arreglo.
function highAndLow(numbers){

  let arr = numbers.split(' ').map(number => parseInt(number));
  let alto = Math.max(...arr);
  let bajo = Math.min(...arr);

  return alto + ' ' + bajo;
}
  //ejemplo
console.log(highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"));
  //salida: 542 - 214
```

Saludos.

Comment: @SJuan76, tienes razon, editada la respuesta, en este ejemplo no lo afecta pero si para otros arreglos donde el min y max puedan estar al inicio,

Comment: El código de @Miguel Zarate junto con la edición de SJuan76 ha sido editado para que abarque un poco menos de lineas de código, cabe mencionar que el código original de Miguel Zarate junto con la edición de SJuan76 trabaja perfectamente!, sin embargo para yo aportar tambien un poco a  su respuesta, pensando en qué podría mejorarse en el código decidí hacerlo mas compacto añadiendole un map y usando las funciónes min y max de javascript.

Comment: no es necesario el map, salvo que agregues una validacion para que calcule bien el valor minimo y maximo, javascript por defecto tranforma el valor en primitivo en este caso trata de llevarlo a flotante